# mod rewrite silent redirect to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a link like this:

```
example.com/site/anyFolderName
```

that i need to be redirected (silently) here:

```
example.com/site/myFolder/anyFolderName
```

and all sub-links be preserved

```
example.com/site/anyFolderName/             (requests)--> example.com/site/myFolder/anyFolderName/
example.com/site/anyFolderName/picture.png  (requests)--> example.com/site/myFolder/anyFolderName/picture.png
example.com/site/anyFolderName/index.html   (requests)--> example.com/site/myFolder/anyFolderName/index.html
example.com/site/anyFolderName/page.php     (requests)--> example.com/site/myFolder/anyFolderName/page.php
```

I fell into the infinite loop with my RewriteRule.Any snippets/tutorials/links/ideas that can point me in the right direction are very welcomed ! Many thanks !

Found this to be quite true:

#### "Despite the tons of examples and docs, mod_rewrite is voodoo. Damned cool voodoo, but still voodoo."

-- Brian Moore

Answer (score 1):

The infinite loop is because you are endlessly matching myFolder no doubt. Need to exclude that from the pattern. Since the match pattern is a Perl Compatible Reguar Expression, You can use a negative, zero width assertion (?!regex)

Add this to server conf or .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site/((?!myFolder/).*)$ site/myFolder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: RewriteRule doesn't start matching first `/`. Replace your rule with: `RewriteRule ^site/((?!myFolder/).*)$ site/myFolder/$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: absolutely correct, your solution is better. answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#to prevent looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#To handle trailing slash problem
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:\.\w+|/)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(site)(/.*) $1/myfolder$2 [L,NC]
```

Although in your case

```
#to prevent looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

will not be required just for the above.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

will take care of the loop termination.

Comment: Thank you for answering ! I changed **RewriteRule (.*) $1/ [R,L]** to **RewriteRule (.*) site/$1/ [R,L]** because it was redirecting to **example.com/anyFolderName**. I get a 404 when i try to access **example.com/site/anyFolderName/abc.html** with the directory structure like : **site/folderName/anyFolderName/abc.html** .Maybe I'm doing something wrong ? Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: @codequp `RewriteRule (.*) $1/` will not strip `/site` from your URL! if `example.com/site/anyFolderName` was accessed it will redirect to `example.com/site/anyFolderName/` and then serve the content from `/site/myfolder/anyFolderName/` without it getting reflected in the browser. Are you sure you typed the correct URL in your browser.

Comment: @codequp Also, I have optimized the code a bit.